# MongoExecutionTimeoutException

Tags: java, android, mongodb, android-studio

I am trying to develop one android app which store contacts on mongo db I had done mogno db connection successfully using ServerMonitorListener.

Here below is my mongo connection class

```
public class ServerConnection implements ServerMonitorListener {

        private MongoClient client;
        private MongoDatabase mongoDb;
        private Context context;
        String hostip = "109.xx.xx.xx", dbname = "contacts";
        String contactSyncDb;
        DB db;
        public static DBCollection contactCollection;
        public static DBCollection allContactCollection;

        public ServerConnection(Context context) {

            this.context = context;
            try {
                MongoClientOptions clientOptions = new MongoClientOptions.Builder()
                        .socketTimeout(5000)
                        .heartbeatSocketTimeout(5000)
                        .addServerMonitorListener(this)
                        .build();

                client = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(hostip, 27017), clientOptions);
                mongoDb = client.getDatabase(dbname);


            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void serverHearbeatStarted(ServerHeartbeatStartedEvent serverHeartbeatStartedEvent) {
           System.out.println("Mongo Connection : Started ");
        }

        @Override
        public void serverHeartbeatSucceeded(ServerHeartbeatSucceededEvent serverHeartbeatSucceededEvent) {
            if (!keepAlive(client)) {
                MongoClientOptions clientOptions = new MongoClientOptions.Builder()
                        .addServerMonitorListener(this)
                        .build();
                client = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(hostip, 27017), clientOptions);
            }
       }

        @Override
        public void serverHeartbeatFailed(ServerHeartbeatFailedEvent serverHeartbeatFailedEvent) {

            MongoClientOptions clientOptions = new MongoClientOptions.Builder()
                    .socketTimeout(5000)
                    .heartbeatSocketTimeout(5000)
                    .addServerMonitorListener(this)
                    .build();
            client = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(hostip, 27017), clientOptions);

        }

        //Check connection is alive or not
        public boolean keepAlive(MongoClient mongoClient) {
            try {
                return mongoClient.getAddress() != null;
            } catch (MongoExecutionTimeoutException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                MongoClientOptions clientOptions = new MongoClientOptions.Builder()
                        .socketTimeout(5000)
                        .heartbeatSocketTimeout(5000)
                        .addServerMonitorListener(this)
                        .build();
                mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(hostip, 27017), clientOptions);
            return mongoClient.getAddress() != null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I prepare one async task from where I adding new contact on server

```
public class MongoAsync extends AsyncTask {

    public Context context;

    public MongoAsync(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {

        ServerConnection serverConnection = new ServerConnection(context);
        return null;
    }

    //Insert record in Mongo Contacts table
    public void insertContacts(DBCollection contactCollection, String firstname, String lastname, String number) {

        BasicDBObject contactRecord = new BasicDBObject();
        contactRecord.put("first_name", firstname);
        contactRecord.put("last_name", lastname);
        contactRecord.put("number", number);

        try {
            System.out.println("Mongo : Insert contact " + firstname + " Number: " + number);
            contactCollection.insert(contactRecord);
        }catch (MongoExecutionTimeoutException e){
            e.printStackTrace();

    }
    }
}
```

And for inserting I use :

```
new MongoAsync(context).insertContacts(contactCollection,"Him", "123", "1234567890");
```

While adding new contact, that time I am getting below error :

> Exception thrown raising server heartbeat succeeded event to listener
>   ServerConnection@27059896
>   com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while
>   waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN,
>   servers=[{address=109.xx.xx.xx:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]

I try a lot to handle that exception by creating interface and implementing it on asynctask but didn't get work.

Is there any way to handle that timeout exception?

Comment: Are you sure that your mongo server is running and accessible by that IP address?

Comment: Yeah, My mongo server is running and accessible. Inserting is also working at initial stage but after some time I am getting that error

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me to solve out this problem?

Comment: in general it's a very bad idea to connect from your phone to database. It's a big security hole here. You should create a server for that.

Comment: You should have REST api to insert contact on your server, not directly to mongodb

Comment: We have created server for that where mongo db had been setup. I have try to insert my contact directly on server db because I made this contact synchronisation globally. Let me explain more For example: I have added one contact from my android device then will get notification on my iOS device and webportal to add that contact in their device also and viceversa. All other things are working fine for my case but getting crash when I have add/remove/edit any contact from native contact book then contactsChangeObserver called and insert/remove contact from their by connecting mongo

Comment: Using REST APIs, Getting time consuming issue while contacts count will be around 1000